# Why is rxJava not showing any effect of BackPressure startegy?

Tags: android, rx-java2

Hi I am quite naive with rxJava, so please let me know if my understanding is correct. As per my understanding if I use backpressure strategy with LATEST flag, I should be getting the most recent value. So I have a list, I am using flowable with subscriber, but it is still printing all values in onNext . Also please let me know how to test this backpressure strategy as I do not have real time data.

Following is my code

```
  Observable.just(listObj).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).
                flatMap(new Function<List<String>, Observable<String>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Observable<String> apply(List<String> ints) {
                        return Observable.fromIterable(ints);
                    }
                }).toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.LATEST).subscribe(new Subscriber<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(Subscription s) {
                s.request(Long.MAX_VALUE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(String s) {
                Log.d("Value", s);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable t) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {

            }
        });
    }
```

///////////
Following is s simple method which creates arraylist

```
  private ArrayList<String> createListForReturn() {
    try {
        if (listObj != null) {
            listObj.add("Thanks");
            listObj.add("fine");
            listObj.add("working");
            listObj.add("is");
            listObj.add("Flowable");
            listObj.add("Now");
            listObj.add("Flowable");
            listObj.add("For");
            listObj.add("Programme");
            listObj.add("RxJava");
            listObj.add("Second");
            listObj.add("My");
            listObj.add("is");
            listObj.add("This");
            listObj.add(" ");
        }
        return listObj;

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: "BackPressure Strategy" in Rx means if you can't consume the `onNext` events quicker than upstream can feed them, what strategy do you want to adopt?.  In your case you are consuming all events quickly enough so the strategy is not required/implemented. Read the docs for more concise information - https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Backpressure-(2.0)

Comment: @MarkKeen thank you,so can you provide me with some example  on how to simulate the backpressure strategy ?

Comment: Block the current thread or do a computation that takes a longer period of time than the time between `onNext` calls in your consumer (subscriber) - have a look at the documentation.

Comment: @MarkKeen you mean this ? .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())

Comment: That, in this particular instance is the thread that will be obsserving `onNext` calls on your subscriber/observer - do you really want to use the main thread as your test bed? All heavy/blocking tasks should not be performed (if possible) on the main thread anyway.

Comment: @MarkKeen this is simply an example so it will not matter to me as long as I am able to simulate it. So if I remove the line it will work ?

Comment: You also need an asynchronous boundary after an `onBackpressureX` to see the effects, otherwise the synchronous nature of RxJava will still get you all items.